# IFRAME (открытие html страниц) в модальном окне

Tags: всплывающее-окно, html, окно, iframe

Друзья! В общем, вот такая задача и проблема одновременно.

Для моего одного специального проекта необходимо открывать новости (html страницы) в модальном окне. Пересмотрел кучу плагинов. В основном все тяжелые, сильно замудренные, не подходят. Понравилась и устроила во всех отношениях реализация - Magnific Popup. Но вот задача! Ну не идет он на сайте, и хоть ты тресни!

Что можете посоветовать? Нужен самый простой плагин, но полностью работающий, включая во всех браузерах, чтобы открывал html во фрейме в модалке. Всё! Других функций не нужно.

Не подумайте, что это лень или еще что-то. Нет, правда, бьюсь уже несколько дней, что только не пробовал, но вот ни в какую не могу подобрать нужный скрипт под конкретно эту задачу. Не пинайте только, не ленивый, наоборот трудоголик. Но вот незадача и все тут!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

example http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3j7dLecf/